# GIT / RubyMine (Leopard) - can't pull but I can commit and push

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, macos, git-pull, rubymine

Ive got weird problem

My system is Snow Leopard (10.6.4) - I can't make pull from my RubyMine but I can make commit and push. The best thing is that when I run terminal and type "git pull" it works fine.

In ruby mine console there are some errors:

```
/usr/local/git/libexec/git-core/git-sh-setup: line 71: basename: command not found
/usr/local/git/libexec/git-core/git-sh-setup: line 71: sed: command not found
/usr/local/git/libexec/git-core/git-sh-setup: line 202: uname: command not found
From git.xxx.xxx
 * branch            yly        -> FETCH_HEAD
/usr/local/git/libexec/git-core/git-pull: line 251: sed: command not found
/usr/local/git/libexec/git-core/git-pull: line 251: tr: command not found
There are no candidates for merging among the refs that you just fetched.
Generally this means that you provided a wildcard refspec which had no
matches on the remote end.
```

I dont know how to solve this stupid problem. Any ideas? Thanks for help

Comment: Maybe it would be easier if you give some more info about your branches and your remotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks man! It was problem with environment variables. Here is the solution:

http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-1160

Answer (score 0):

apparently environment variables are missing in your rubymine console, so it cannot find those executables(sed, uname etc.).